# How can I fake/mock the Geolocation in the ChromeDriver through Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, gps, selenium-chromedriver

How can I fake/mock the Geolocation in the ChromeDriver through Selenium in C#?

I only examples for Python and Java but I cannot "translate" the code to C# because the used functions do not exist.

This is a example image of what I want to do:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to official, it seems not supported yet.
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

I can think of 2 options here

- Try and find if it possible using Chrome State file, using `localState` capability. Note, ***you cannot change it on runtime***.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

- Set Appium driver with real/emulator device and use

```
self.driver.set_location(49, 123, 10)
```

```
driver.Location.Altitude = 94.23;
driver.Location.Latitude = 121.21;
driver.Location.Longitude = 11.56;
```

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/geolocation/set-geolocation/

To change the location whenever you like. I think this is the best way to do it anyway, even if it is easier to just use Chrome instead of configure Appium server.